# How to write query for date in mongolab?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

i have stored data like this

```
"C_Newsletter": {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-20T09:52:26.498Z"
        }
    },
```

For this how can i write query for date search in mongolab.here i want to search
2015-10-20 .where ever 2015-10-20 matches i need to show
i am new to mongo lab some one help me out for this.i have written like this

```
{
    "C_Newsletter": {
        "date": {
            "$date": "2015-10-20T09:52:26.498Z"
        }
    }
}
```

but its showing only one data .becoz of exact time and date.my expectation i want to get entire 2015-10-20 data

Comment: use `$get` and `$lte`

Comment: pls can you add full query for this

Comment: @martinn I don't use mongolab, but in general query should be something like this `{"C_Newsletter":{"date":{"$gte":ISODate("2015-10-20")},"$lte":ISODate("2015-10-20")}}`

Comment: @Undefined_variable .i am getting JSON Validation error

Answer (score 0):

Create a date range query using the **[`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt)** and **[`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/lte/#op._S_lte)** operators where you search for dates between a particular range i.e. end of previous day to end of day in question, something like the following:

```
{
    "C_Newsletter": {
        "date": {
            "$gt": { "$date": "2015-10-19T23:59:59.999Z" },
            "$lte": { "$date": "2015-10-20T23:59:59.999Z" }
        }
    }
}
```